# verify the occurence of an element a set of times between every pair of digits that add up to 10 Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to write a predicate verify(List,Elt,Occ) that succeeds if Elt occurs exactly Occ times between every pair of digits that add up to 10.

For example:

- `verify([a,r,b,6,?,?,?,4,x,x,b,1,5,?,?,?,e,e,e,5],?,3)` should return `true`
- `verify([a,a,6,?,9],?,3)` should return `false`
- `verify([9,?,?,?,1,?,?,?,9,?,?,?,1,?,?,?,9],?,3)` should return `true`
- `verify([5,?,?,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,?,5,?,5],?,3)` should return `false`

my code so far is:

```
verify( [],    _,   _   ) .
verify( [H|T], Elt, Occ ) :-
  integer(H),
  Y=H,
  verifyWithNb(T,Elt,Occ,Y,0).
verify( [H|T], Elt, Occ ) :-
  \+integer(H),
  verify(T,Elt,Occ).

verifyWithNb( [H|T], Elt, Occ, Y, Help ) :-
  H==Elt,
  New is Help+1,
  verifyWithNb(T,Elt,Occ,Y,New) .
verifyWithNb( [H|T], Elt, Occ, Y, Help ) :-
  Occ==Help,
  integer(H),
  Y+H==10,
  verify(T,Elt,Occ).
```

Comment: Why should `verify([9,?,?,?,1,?,?,?,9,?,?,?,9],?,3)` "return" `true` for `Occ=3` and not `Occ=6`? I see six question marks between pairs of digits (numbers?), i.e., the pairs `9,?,?,?,1` and the pair `1,?,?,?,9`. Must a number not be considered twice? If yes, what about `[9,?,?,?,1,?,?,?,9,?,?,?,?,9]` where both pairs have a different number of occurrences?

Comment: @Dr.MarkusWeninger when someone made an edit to the question they messed up the example by mistake I fixed it now

Comment: What exactly should cause `verify([a,a,6,?,9],?,3)` to fail?

Answer (score 0):

I might do that something along these lines:

- find an integer, handing back a *prefix* (the elements before it), the integer, and the *suffix* (the elements after it)
- looking at the _suffix, find an integer
- verify that the two integers thus found sum to 10, and
- verify that the second prefix found is of the correct length and contains only the specified atom

```
verify(Xs, A, N ) :-
    find_int(Xs,_,X,X1),
    find_int(X1,As,Y,_),
    X+Y =:= 10,
    valid(As,N,A).

find_int( [X|Xs] ,     []  , X, Xs  ) :-    integer(X) .
find_int( [X|Xs] ,    Pfx  , N, Sfx ) :-    integer(X), find_int(Xs,Pfx,N,Sfx) .
find_int( [X|Xs] , [X|Pfx] , N, Sfx ) :- \+ integer(X), find_int(Xs,Pfx,N,Sfx) .

valid([],0,_).
valid([A|As],N,A) :- N1 is N-1, valid(As,N1,A).
```

Or you could just use `append/3`:

```
verify( Xs, A, N ) :-
  append( _  , [X|X1] , Xs ) ,
  append( As , [Y|_]  , X1 ) ,
  X+Y =:= 10 ,
  valid(As,N,A) .

valid([],0,_).
valid([A|As],N,A) :- N1 is N-1, valid(As,N1,A).
```

Another approach might be to *run-length encode* the list,

```
run_length_encode( []     , [] ) .
run_length_encode( [X|Xs] , Rs ) :- rle( Xs, X:1, Rs ) .

rle( []     , X:N , [X:N]    ) .
rle( [X|Xs] , X:N , Rs       ) :- N1 is N+1, rle(Xs,X:N1,Rs).
rle( [X|Xs] , Y:N , [Y:N|Rs] ) :- X \= Y, rle(Xs,X:1,Rs).
```

converting

```
[9,?,?,?,1,?,?,?,9,?,?,?,9]
```

is converted to

```
[ 9:1, (?):3, 1:1, (?):3, 9:1, (?):3, 9:1]
```

Then it's just a matter of iterating over the run-length encoded list looking for the desired pattern:

```
verify( Xs, A, N ) :-
    run_length_encode(Xs,Rs),
    append(_,[X:_,A:N,Y:_|_],Rs),
    X+Y =:= 10.

run_length_encode( [] , [] ) .
run_length_encode( [X|Xs] , Rs ) :- rle( Xs, X:1, Rs ) .

rle( []     , X:N , [X:N]    ) .
rle( [X|Xs] , X:N , Rs       ) :- N1 is N+1, rle(Xs,X:N1,Rs).
rle( [X|Xs] , Y:N , [Y:N|Rs] ) :- X \= Y, rle(Xs,X:1,Rs).
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using DCG:

```
verify(Lst, Char, Len) :-
    phrase(verify_(Char, Len), Lst).

% Success if reached end of list
verify_(_, _) --> [].
verify_(Char, Len) -->
    [C],
    { digit_t(C, Bool) },
    verify_char(Bool, C, Char, Len),
    verify_(Char, Len).

verify_char(true, D1, Char, Len) -->
    verify_digit(Char, Len, D1).
% Skip over non-digits which are not contained within a digit pair
verify_char(false, _, _, _) --> [].


verify_digit(Char, Len, D1), [D2] -->
    string_of(Char, Len),
    [D2],
    { digit(D2) },
    { 10 is D1 + D2 }, !.
verify_digit(_Char, _Len, D1), [D2] -->
    string_without_digits,
    [D2],
    { digit(D2) }, !,
    { \+ 10 is D1 + D2 }.
% Greedily consume
verify_digit(_, _, _) --> [].

% Can be adapted as desired
string_of(Char, Len) -->
    { integer(Len) },
    string_of_(Char, Len).

string_of_(Char, Len) -->
    { compare(Comp, Len, 0) },
    string_of_comp_(Comp, Char, Len).

string_of_comp_(=, _, _) --> [].
string_of_comp_(>, Char, Len) -->
    [Char],
    { Len0 is Len - 1 },
    string_of_(Char, Len0).


string_without_digits -->
    [C],
    { \+ digit(C) }, !,
    string_without_digits.
% Greedily consume
string_without_digits --> [].


digit(D) :-
    (nonvar(D) -> integer(D) ; true),
    between(0, 9, D).

digit_t(D, Bool) :-
    (digit(D) *-> Bool = true ; Bool = false).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- verify([4,?,6],?,1), !.
true.

?- verify([4,?,6,?,4],?,1), !.
true.

?- verify([4,?,6,?,?,4],?,1), !.
false.

?- verify([4,?,6,?,?,9],?,1), !.
true.
```